# How to do UNION in flexible query

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to merge `catetegory_id` and `subCategory_id` into one column. But I don't know how to do it in flexible query. Below code is what I want to do

```
SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT
    ccr.targetpk as pk
    FROM
    Categories cc
    JOIN Cat2CatRel ccr ON cc.pk = ccr.sourcepk
    WHERE cc.p_code = '0106') 

UNION  SELECT CATE.pk as pk FROM CATEGORIES cate WHERE CATE.p_code = '0106'
```

I need a flexible query which works same as above code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is possible to do unions in flexible search queries. Here is an example like your case:

```
SELECT uniontable.PK FROM
(
   {{
      SELECT {cc:PK} as PK, {cc:code} AS CODE FROM {Categories AS cc}
      WHERE {cc:p_code} LIKE '0106'
   }}
   UNION ALL
   {{
      SELECT {ccr:PK} as PK, {ccr:code} AS CODE FROM {Cat2CatRel AS ccr}
      WHERE {ccr:p_code} LIKE '0106'
   }}
) uniontable
```

Here you can find some more information about flex searches: [Hybris Wiki](https://help.hybris.com/6.3.0/hcd/8bc36ba986691014b48be171221d1f4f.html)